# How to complete a serie index with a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this serie:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'poste1': 1, 'poste3': 2, 'poste4': 1}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['poste1', 'poste3', 'poste4'])
print(ser)
```

I would like to complete the value this the missing codification :

```
liste_poste=['poste1','poste2','poste3','poste4','poste5']
```

result expected :
[image]

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Can you share the code with the data a bit or minimal data so that I can play around with it?

Comment: I just add minimal example. Sorry for the lack of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reindex` it and use the `fill_value` parameter to fill missing values with 0 (so that we don't mess up the dtype of the Series):

```py
out = ser.reindex(liste_poste, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```py
poste1    1
poste2    0
poste3    2
poste4    1
poste5    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the list to a series as well, you can use pandas' `combine` method for series:

```py
series_poste = pd.Series({k: 0 for k in liste_poste})
ser = ser.combine(series_poste, func=np.add, fill_value=0)
print(ser)
```

```
poste1    1
poste2    0
poste3    2
poste4    1
poste5    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

After having the series, you can do something like this to get the list.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
list_entries = ['a','b','c','d']
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(ser)
found = list(ser [ser  > 0].index)
print([x for x in list_entries if x not in found])
```

Output:

```
['d']
```